# Is there a recent precedent of a Western government classifying previously public information as a secret?

Tags: europe, classified-information

According to [this Romania Insider article](https://www.romania-insider.com/romanian-president-visit-asia-aircraft-debate-2023), the costs for the president's transportation represent classified information:

> The presidential administration stated in a response to Digi24 that securing air transportation for President Iohannis during the official visits to Japan and Singapore was based on a service contract for special flights concluded according to a regulation approved by the government decision. At the same time, the institution noted that the type of aircraft and **the costs of this trip cannot be made public because they are "classified information.”**

A Romanian NGO (Recorder) dug more into the classified aspect of the costs as shown in [this article](https://recorder.ro/din-absurdul-epocii-iohannis-sah-mat-cu-propriile-secrete/?utm_source=recorder.beehiiv.com&utm_medium=newsletter&utm_campaign=lumea-minunata-a-pre-edintelui-iohannis) (Romanian). I will include a quick overview of the article here:

- Recorder asked the Presidential Administration back in 2015 about the costs associated with the first official flight of the current Romanian President (Iohannis) and received the information
- Recorder asks about the same cost in 2023 and this time the response mentions that the information is classified
- as a consequence information that was available in 2015 is considered "classified" right now

As a side note, Recorder decided to sue the Presidential Administration in an effort to lift the secrecy over how the public funds are being spent.

I am wondering if this happened before in a European country. Is there a recent precedent of a European government classifying previously public information as a secret?

Comment: Would you accept an answer from the US? https://www.nytimes.com/2006/02/21/politics/us-reclassifies-many-documents-in-secret-review.html

Comment: France used to "secret defense" quite a bit of expense-related crap, but mostly to avoid releasing information that had never been public in the first place.  Here's (French) an example as [recent as 2014, keeping D-Day 70th anniversary event costs out of sight](https://www.tf1info.fr/politique/le-d-day-rapportera-4-milliards-quand-le-gouvernement-manipule-les-chiffres-1551199.html)

Comment: Are you saying that information pertaining to the 2015 trip, which was previously released, is classified, or only the new trip? I could certainly understand if a) Romania has tightened its security in the last 8 years and b) it's not eager to explain how.

Comment: @Cadence According to Recorder (which also showed the documents in a video), they asked for and received the expenses back in 2015. Now, they have asked again for data about the very same trip and did not receive it. One of the points in the article (and the video) mentions that they do not know what to do with the information since it has become classified in the meantime.

Comment: @JonathanReez yes, I have just edited the question to also allow answers for the US.

Comment: Not recent, but my father when he was in the Army in the 1950s recalls a barracks mate telling the tale of classifying the front page of the New York Times once.

Comment: @JonathanReez NYT is paywalled, so can you summarize what they say?  I did listen to a podcast recently about US classification procedures - specifically classifying internal citations of US newspaper articles.  The expert stated it's most likely to keep officials looking clean:  "What do you mean, you never heard of civilian casualties in Afghanistan coalition strikes?  This DoD memo discusses the fallout of the Jan 26th Washington Post article about the wedding party bombing disaster".  The podcast in general was very critical of overclassification and under-declassification.